# Selecting ad with the least number of views

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql statement where i am trying to get the ad with the lowest number of views:

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE type='crossPromo' AND city='$city' AND views= ( SELECT MIN(views) FROM ads ) AND expire >= '$today' LIMIT 1";
```

Once it selects an ad, it increases the views column by one.

It all works perfectly. ONCE.   It seems once all ads==1 it won't just choose a random ad, or the first ad, but doesn't return anything.

Is there any way to get it to return an add when they are all equal?

Comment: Seeing things like `$city` in your query is highly worrying. Are you sure you're properly escaping that value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select a.*
from ads
where type = 'crosspromo' and city = '$city' and expire >= '$today'
order by views
limit 1;
```

The problem with your query is that it is returning the minimum over *all* ads in the subquery.  However, that minimum may not satisfy the other conditions, so nothing is returned.

Comment: Do you mean if there is two identical values in database then `MIN()` cannot choose of them and it returns nothing?

Comment: @Shafizadeh  . . . No, that is not what I mean.  I mean that the minimum over all ads may not be in the city you care about.